# A plain text viewer which can hide lines that meet specified regexps

Tags: software-recommendation, text-editor, text

Each time I've been looking for "something I don't know exactly what" in big text file, e.g. log-file, huge shell script, I wish to hide all the lines of certain types.

I wish to select certain lines with a set of regexps and either hide them or highlight.

It would be nice if I could select line blocks e.g. those lines between 
"function ...()
{"
and corresponding
"}"

can you suggest me such a viewer?

Comment: I like `egrep` although it has to be used from the terminal. Assuming you are in the directory that holds the file called `input`, `egrep -v '^#|^ *$' input > output` will exclude lines that are commented with a `#` at the beginning of lines and lines that are not blank and write the results to the file called `output` in the same folder.
Obviously, you can modify the criteria depending on the content of your file.

Comment: Many text editors will do syntax highlighting. Tools such as grep, awk, perl will help you search your logs.

Comment: yes i'm aware of grep, awk, other cool text processing stuff, but in the context I described abowe I find them not convenient.

I need **GUI** **viewer** with ability to switch on/off certain regexp by clicking a checkbox, also it would be very helpful to have an option to extract to separate tab all the lines with defined regexp.

Comment: **gnome-system-log** has such filters but they are implemented such way, that I could hardly use them.

Answer (score 4):

Here are 5 of the best viewers

[MultiTail](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20100604190126761/MultiTail.html)  View multiple logfiles windowed on the console

[System Log Viewer](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20100604203626537/SystemLogViewer.html)  A system log viewer for GNOME

[KSystemLog](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20100604190816260/KSystemLog.html)     System log viewer for KDE 4

[Xlogmaster](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/2010060419080073/Xlogmaster.html)     GTK+ based program to keep track of logfiles and devices

[Swatch](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20100604190835932/swatch.html)     Logfile viewer with regexp matching, highlighting & hooks

[source](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20100603155736857/LogfileViewers.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [regexxer](http://regexxer.sourceforge.net/)? It can highlight matches and you can jump from match to match but it won't filter just matches. Similarly like gnome-system-log but more easy to use

I could also show you how to filter regex matches (display only matching lines) in SciTE editor, with small LUA script, and I imagine many others can show you how to with vim or emacs, but you didn't mention which editor you use.

Comment: Thank you for url, I found regexxer very helpful utility. But I need other tool. When I look at a file which contains many lines e.g. when I study ubuntu logs, I want to hide all the lines I know meaning of. That helps to unearth lines I'd like to learn more about. I prefer gvim.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **Geany** [GUI]

regx for multiple line is not supported bust you can use **-** and **+** to hide/show portion of text such as functions (**{...}**).

It support may languages including xml.

http://www.geany.org

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `vim` with `folds`? It can fold code blocks very well.

```
:set foldmethod=indent
```

This command sets fold method based on indentation.